# Commutation Relation between Annihilation & Creation Operators and Ascending & Descending Operators

Tags: quantum-mechanics, optics, operators, fourier-transform, commutator

I am currently working on a QD-Cavity system. After the point Heisenberg Equation of motion is obtained from corresponding Hamiltonian of the system, in order to find the expression for bosonic annihilation operator in frequency domain I have to take Fourier Transform of the following expression:

$
\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}{\hat{c_{j}}}=-i[\hat{c_{j}},H_{j}]-\Gamma _{j}\hat{c_{j}}+i\sqrt{\kappa _{1,j}}(\hat{a{_{in}}^{(j)}}+\hat{b{_{in}}^{(j)}})$

$
\frac{\mathrm{d} }{\mathrm{d} t}{\hat{\sigma_{-,j}}}=-i[\hat{\sigma_{-,j}},H_{j}]-\gamma _{j}\hat{\sigma_{-,j}}+\sqrt{\gamma _{j}^{'}}\hat{\sigma_{j}^{'}} $

**where**

$H_{j}=\omega _{c,j}\hat{c_{j}^{dagger}\hat{c_{j}}}+\omega _{r,j}\hat{\sigma _{+,j}}\hat{\sigma _{-,j}}+[g_{j}(\vec{r})\hat{\sigma _{+,j}}\hat{c_{j}}+H.C.]$

$\kappa _{1,j}$ is the Intrinsic Cavity Decay Rate

$\hat{c_{j}}$ is the bosonic annihilation operator of the jth cavity mode with resonant frequency $\omega _{c,j}$

$\omega _{r,j}$ transition frequency in two level QD-System

$2\Gamma _{j}$ is total cavity decay,  where $\Gamma _{j}= (\kappa _{0,j}+2\kappa _{1,j})/2 $

$\gamma _{j}$ total decay rate

${\gamma _{j}^{'}}$ and $ \hat{\sigma_{j}^{'}}$ vacuum noise operator and associated decay rate

$\hat{\sigma _{+,j}} (\hat{\sigma _{-,j}})$ ascending and descending operator

$g_{j}(\vec{r})$ is the coupling strength between the cavity mode and the dipolar transition

$a{_{in}}^{(j)}(b{_{in}}^{(j)})$ and $a{_{out}}^{(j)}(b{_{out}}^{(j)})$ describe the input and output fields in the left (right) port

---

My questions are:

1. What is the commutation relation between annihilation & creation operators and ascending&descending operators?
2. How can I take their Fourier Transform?

Comment: Welcome to Physics Stack Exchange. Please write equations instead of pasting images. Images cannot be edited and so we strongly discourage using them for math.

Comment: The sigmas and c's commute since they are operators corresponding to different degrees of freedom.